# Email testing not showing site logo in Mailtrap inbox - XAMPP (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I'm currently testing email messages on MailTrap, however my logo is not showing up in the email. i have tried these two markups.

`<img src="http://mysite.me/mysite/public/logos/website_logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" border="0" width="140" height="50">`

`<img src="public/logos/website_logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" border="0" width="140" height="50">`

Someone please help me out.

Comment: Is the domain you are using publicly available? Some email providers will put images through a proxy, so if the images are not available outside your environment, they may not work.

Comment: The domain isn't publicly available, it's just the normal local domain made in the vhost of xampp.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call it this way: `<img src="{{ asset('/path/to/image') }}"`

Comment: Thanks for the solution @L.Fox, but I'm sorry to tell you that it didn't work. Maybe I'm the one not doing it right. Here are my attempts..                                            
 `{{ asset('mysite.me/public/logos/website_logo.png') }}`                                  
`{{ asset('mysite/public/logos/website_logo.png') }}`                                              
 `{{ asset('public/logos/website_logo.png') }}`                                                        
 `{{ asset('../public/logos/website_logo.png') }}` . Actually my images are already inside my Public folder

Comment: How are you storing the image?

Comment: The image is stored in this format: (All that is here is my laravel application itself........)/public/logos/website_logo.png